# Hibernate search 6 with Hibernate 6.2.5

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm trying to migrate my application from spring boot 2.7.6 to 3.1.0 which uses jakarta api and hibernate 6.2.5. The version of the hibernate search that I use is 6.1.5 which depends on hibernate-core 5.6.8. My question is there a way to use hibernate search with hibernate 6.2.5 and spring boot 3.1 or this is still a work in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate Search supports Hibernate ORM 6 as well, you would want to use the `-orm6` versions of the artifacts.

```xml
<!-- other Hiberante Search dependencies -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm-orm6</artifactId> 
   <version>6.1.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#other-integrations-orm6 for more details.

Comment: Thanks! My mistake was that I used the jakarta dependency instead because of java 17 but it seems that the orm6 is the one that needs to be used.